# Why use drywall tape when you can just mud over the crack?

Tags: drywall, patching-drywall

Got a semi-small drywall project with several "joints" and just wondering what would happen if I didnt use the tape? (corners and "butt-joints")

Comment: The mesh tape is like rebar in concrete. It helps by reducing the stress when expansion and contraction occur due to temperature and moisture variation there by reducing the likelihood of cracking.

Comment: I figured someone had to have asked this before, thank you!

Comment: Building on what Dan D. said, tape does reduce the likelihood of cracking.  In my experience however, paper tape will reduce stress much better than mesh tape.  Mesh is woven two directions and can shift in a way that paper cannot.  Mesh will not restrict the walls from shifting up and down, only further away and closer together.